# JS отдача файла клиенту

Tags: php, javascript, reactjs, symfony

Есть вопрос. Суть - на сервере Symfony, контроллер генерирует .po файл из записей в БД и отдаёт клиенту. Фронтенд на React и вопрос - как из полученных данных собрать файл, чтобы дать его скачать?

Сервер отдает его таким образом

```
private function generatePoResponse($filename, $content)
    {
        $response = new Response();

        $response->headers->set('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/x-po');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.po"');

        $response->setContent($content);

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Кажется можно было бы запросить данный файл в скрытом iframe, тогда браузер предложит его скачать без смены текущей страницы

Comment: Кажется именно так работают сайты файлохранилища, которые начинают загрузку по прошествии некоторого времени автоматически

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko мне задержка в принципе не нужна, просто получаю содержимое файла с заголовками и прочим, надо тупо придумать как всё собрать в кучу и отдать

Comment: так я и говорю, в скрытом ифрейме направьте браузер на ссылку, по которой сервер отдаёт файл и браузер предложит его скачать. вы же не хотите делать эту работу за браузер. Если вы хотите формировать файл на клиенте, тогда вот пример как можно скачать блоб на компьютер клиента https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko ваш пример помог, оформите ответ и закрою вопрос) спасибо за подсказку